# Почему вызываются методы базового класса вместо переопределённых?

Tags: c++

Почему вызываются методы базового класса вместо переопределённых?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class Publication 
{
    private:
        std::string title;
        float price;

    public:
        virtual void set_data() 
        {
            std::cout << "\n Enter title: "; std::cin >> title;
            std::cout << " Enter price: ";  std::cin >> price;
        }
        virtual void show_data()const
        {
            std::cout << "\n title: " << title;
            std::cout << "\n price: " << price << " $";
        }


};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Book : public Publication
{
    private:
        int pages;

    public:
        void set_data()
        {
            Publication::set_data();
            std::cout << " Set book pages: "; std::cin >> pages;
        }
        void show_data()
        {
            Publication::show_data();
            std::cout << "\n pages: " << pages << std::endl;
        }
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Tape : public Publication
{
    private:
        float time;

    public:
        void set_data()
        {
            Publication::set_data();
            std::cout << " Set tape time: "; std::cin >> time;
        }
        void show_data()
        {
            Publication::show_data();
            std::cout << "\n time: " << time << " min" << std::endl;
        }

};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{
    Publication* pubarr[100];

    int n = 0;
    char chose;

    do {
        std::cout << "Enter data for book or tape (b/t)?"; std::cin >> chose;

        if (chose == 'b') 
            { pubarr[n] = new Book; } 
        else 
            { pubarr[n] = new Tape; }

        pubarr[n++]->set_data();

        std::cout << "\n Again (y/n)?"; std::cin >> chose;
    } while (chose == 'y');

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        pubarr[i]->show_data();
    }

    return 0;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: `Publication::set_data();` вы же их сами вызываете. Переопределённые методы тоже вызываются... https://ideone.com/hfbrbS тут видно что был вызов у наследника

Comment: да, но почему при выводе информации метод show_data() вызывается у базового класса?

Comment: const - часть сигнатуры

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> да, но почему при выводе информации метод show_data() вызывается у
>   базового класса?

Потому что в наследниках у метода show_data другая сигнатура.
В базе он у вас

```
virtual void show_data() const; // <- CONST!
```

А в наследниках этого const нет. Для компилятора это другие методы.

Чтобы таких ошибок избегать надо использовать слово `override` (с с++11) у наследников, тогда компилятор выдаст ошибку, что-то типа такого метода в базовом классе нет.

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void show() const;
}

class SubBase : public Base
{
public:
    void show() const override; // начиная с с++11
    // void show() override; Компилятор будет ругаться
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое) я думал const не входит в сигнатуру)